# Iterate back to zero in MS Excel Caeser Cipher code

Tags: excel, vba

How do I iterate back to zero in a Microsoft Excel Caeser Cipher code?

I've tried:

```
If Letter_value + Offset > 25 Then
    Letter_value Offset = Letter_value + Offset - 25
```

This does not work.

Comment: Please consider showing more of your code. I'm sure that makes perfect sense to you, but we don't have the context you do.

Answer (score 0):

I think I figured out what you're asking.
Take a look at the [mod operator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa242823%28v=vs.60%29.aspx).

This function assumes that your alphabet starts with 1 = "A" and your alphabet only consists of the letters A-Z.

```
Function simpleCeaserEncode(letter_value As Integer, offset As Integer) As Integer
' returns simple ceaser encoded value of of the letter_value

    If letter_value + offset > 25 Then
        simpleCeaserEncode = (letter_value + offset) Mod 26
    Else
        simpleCeaserEncode = letter_value + offset
    End If
End Function

Private Sub test()
    Debug.Print simpleCeaserEncode(20, 10)
    ' ==> 4
    Debug.Print simpleCeaserEncode(20, 2)
    ' ==> 22
End Sub
```